# Woocommerce Sort by default variation price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have used the below code to show the default variation price on the products page instead of the price range.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
        $def=true;
        foreach($product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
            if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                $def=false;             
            }   
        }
        if($def){
            $price = $pav['display_price'];         
        }
    }   

    return woocommerce_price($price);

}
```

The problem is when then products are sorted by price, it uses the lowest variation price instead of the default.
How can I set it so when sorting by price uses the default variation price instead?

Answer (score 1):

`get_variation_default_attributes` and `woocommerce_price` are depreciated.

This works for me. If I have set default attributes.

```php
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
        $def=true;
        foreach($product->get_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
            if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                $def=false;             
            }   
        }
        if($def){
            $price = $pav['display_price'];         
        }
    }   
    return wc_price($price);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried replacing my code with this and it is now showing the variation range for the price instead of the default variation. It also has not changed the sort order, e.g. sorting my lowest to highest still uses the lowest variation instead of the default value.

Comment: Do you have a default variation set?  Which version of WooCommerce are you using?